AWS S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch Presigned Request
I am implementing image upload to AWS S3 storage, currently I can't solve the "SingatureDoesNotMatch" error when uploading using the pre-signed URL.
My frontend call looks like this, I retrieve the pre-signed URL but when I try to use it for upload I get the 403 forbidden.
const uploadImageToS3 = async (file, leagueId) => {
  const backendUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL || 'http://localhost:8080';
  const jwtToken = Cookies.get('jwtToken');
  const objectKey = `-event-${file.name}`;
  const url = `${backendUrl}/aws/generate-presigned-url?fileName=${objectKey}&contentType=image/jpeg`;

  try {
    const authOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    // Fetch the presigned URL from your backend
    const response = await fetchWithAuth(url, authOptions, () => console.log('Logout or handle auth failure'));

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to obtain presigned URL');
    }

    let presignedUrl = await response.text();

    // Use the presigned URL to upload the file to S3
    const result = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "image/jpeg",
      },
      body: file
    });

    if (!result.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to upload image to S3');
    }

    console.log('Uploaded successfully!');
    return objectKey;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image to S3:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

Backend method (bucket name and credentials are correct):
@GetMapping("/generate-presigned-url")
    public ResponseEntity<?> generatePresignedUrl(@RequestParam String fileName, @RequestParam String contentType) {
        System.out.println(contentType + " filename: " + fileName);
        try {
            // Set the expiry time. Adjust based on your needs.
            Date expiration = new Date();
            long expTimeMillis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
            expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 5;
            expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

            // Generate the pre-signed URL.
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fileName)
                            .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                            .withExpiration(expiration)
                            .withContentType(contentType);

            URL url = amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(url.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body("Error generating URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


Are you sure 403 is not a result of CORS error?. try opening Developer tools from browser and see if you can get more details for 403. You need to allow presigned Url S3 domain to be allowed by your site if that's the cause.

also, does your S3 bucket Permissions allow CORS from your site domain?
